# How to change wordpress post title?

Tags: plugin-development, title, filters

How to change just wordpress post title but not menu items.

```
add_filter('the_title', 'wordpress_title');
function wordpress_title(){
  return 'New title';
}
```

[image]

Comment: Use `in_the_loop()` conditional check.

Answer (score 1):

```
add_filter('the_title', 'wordpress_title');
function wordpress_title($title){

    //Return new title if called inside loop
    if ( in_the_loop() )
        return 'New title';

    //Else return regular   
    return $title;

}
```

Have you tried the *[`in_the_loop()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/in_the_loop)* conditional check to return new title only if called inside loop. That means nav menu's will not get affected.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using custom nav menus, you can do this entirely without code.  Go to `Appearance` -> `Menus` and change the "Navigation Label" of each menu item you want to be different.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php add_filter('the_title', function($title) { return '<b>'. $title. '</b>';}) ?>
```

Comment: Menu items ant post name now bold. I need change just post title (<h2>) and not menu items.

Comment: Modify the theme, and not the filter.

Answer (score 0):

You need the right set of contditions:

- Inside the loop
- The ID of the post matches the id from the URL (a bit complex)
- ...Other optional conditions

Place this in your plugin or theme:

```
add_filter( 'the_title', 'change_my_title');
function change_my_title ($title) {
    if ( in_the_loop() && get_the_ID() === url_to_postid(full_url($_SERVER))) {
        $title = $title . " added by plugin";
    }
    return $title;
}

// Function found here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8891890/358906
function full_url($s) {
    $ssl = (!empty($s['HTTPS']) && $s['HTTPS'] == 'on') ? true:false;
    $sp = strtolower($s['SERVER_PROTOCOL']);
    $protocol = substr($sp, 0, strpos($sp, '/')) . (($ssl) ? 's' : '');
    $port = $s['SERVER_PORT'];
    $port = ((!$ssl && $port=='80') || ($ssl && $port=='443')) ? '' : ':'.$port;
    $host = isset($s['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST']) ? $s['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST'] : isset($s['HTTP_HOST']) ? $s['HTTP_HOST'] : $s['SERVER_NAME'];
    return $protocol . '://' . $host . $port . $s['REQUEST_URI'];
}
```